How can I ensure a table can be scrolled horizontally if the screen is too small?
I'm trying to have a Card with a Table that cab be horizontally scrolled if the screen is too small.
The following is the relevant code:
Widget buildScrollableCard(Object m) {
  return MyCard(
    shadow: MyShadow(elevation: 0.5),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 800,
              width: 2600,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: m.data!.rowCount > 0
                    ? buildTable(m, m.home, true)
                    : Text("Nothing to show"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildTable(Object m, Object t, bool h) {
  return MyCard(
    shadow: MyShadow(elevation: 0.5),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: MySpacing.x(flexSpacing),
          child: PaginatedDataTable(
            header: Row(
              children: [
                MyText.titleMedium(
                  "Title",
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            arrowHeadColor: Colors.red,
            source: h ? m.data! : m.secondarydata!,
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                  label: MyText.bodyMedium(
                'Name',
                fontWeight: 600,
              )),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('1')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('2')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('3')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('4')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('5')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('6')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('7')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('8')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('9')),
              DataColumn(label: MyText.bodyMedium('10')),
            ],
            columnSpacing: 300,
            horizontalMargin: 28,
            rowsPerPage: 11,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

When the table does not fit into the page it just cannot be scrolled, so I don't see all the columns.
How can I have ensure that the table can be scrolled if the screen is too small?
I need this to be scrollable on the browser and the mobile
EDIT
The following code is a minimized version of my code. Vertically it scroll but not horizontally:
Any idea why?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Horizontal Scroll Example'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // Set scroll direction to horizontal
          child: Row(
            children: List.generate(30, (index) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks

You have multiple options you can consider,
1- and the best for me to install emulator with small dimension
2- try to insert or write fake objects that holds too long data

Hi, thanks. The fact is that the objects aren't scrollable even if I put a lot of objects... I think the problem is somewhere else

Hi no worries at all , at the beginning try to remove the fixed width and you may try to wrap the scroll view inside expanded however wrapping expanded inside stack would case issues as the ui may not render correctly
